# Compare multiple CSV columns and return complete data from both in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, compareobject

I have two spreadsheets with data which I want to compare to highlight matching and non-matching data with a few "gotchas" - some columns I want to ignore for comparison (score, testname), others I want to include (Filename and hash), and I want to passthru both sides (so even if it doesn't match, I want to do a "full outer" query). Here's my example data:

CSV1 (Source):

```
FileName, ServerName, TestName, Hash,  Score
C:\temp,  ServerA,    TestA,    12345, 100
C:\temp1, ServerA,    TestA,    12345, 100
C:\temp2, ServerA,    TestA,    12345, 5
C:\temp3, ServerA,    TestA,    8888,  100
C:\temp5, serverA,    TestB,    9999,  100
```

CSV2 (ComparisonTarget):

```
FileName, ServerName, TestName, Hash,  Score
C:\temp,  ServerB,    TestA,    12345, 100
C:\temp1, ServerB,    TestA,    5555,  100
C:\temp3, ServerB,    TestA,    8888,  100
C:\temp5, ServerB,    TestB,    9999,  100
C:\temp7, ServerB,    TestB,    5678,  22
```

I want to see if Filenames and hashes match - e.g.
C:\temp and C:\temp5 would match 
and return all columns with a side indicator - e.g.

Output CSV

```
SourceFileName, SourceServer,DestinationServer, ..., Match, Score
C:\temp,        ServerA,     ServerB,                True, 100
C:\temp3,       ServerA,     ServerB,                True, 8888
C:\temp1,       ServerA,     ServerB,                False, 100
C:\temp2,       ServerA,     N/A,                    False, 5
C:\temp7,       N/A,         ServerB,                False, 22
```

I have used a ForEach($record in $CSV1) and checked for matching Filenames, then Hashes, but it's slow with large amounts of data (I suspect because my full outer query requires me to extend my hashtable with new members for all columns).

I figured Compare-object would be a good fit but that doesn't seem to allow me to include both sides in a passthru statement unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't output.csv have a False in the 2nd row as the hash doesn't match?

Comment: @LotPings You are quite right - I've amended this now.

Comment: I would build a hashtable (`@{}`) from the comparison target and write a `foreach` loop over the input file. No reason to make this any more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join):

```
$CSV1 | FullJoin $CSV2 -On FileName -Property @{
    SourceFileName = {If ($Left.FileName) {$Left.FileName} Else {$Right.FileName}}
    SourceServer = {$Left.ServerName}
    DestinationServer = {$Right.ServerName}
    Match = {$Left.Hash -eq $Right.Hash}
    Score = {If ($Left.$_ -gt $Right.$_) {$Left.$_} Else {$Right.$_}}
} |Format-Table

Match DestinationServer Score SourceFileName SourceServer
----- ----------------- ----- -------------- ------------
 True ServerB           100   C:\temp        ServerA
False ServerB           100   C:\temp1       ServerA
False                   5     C:\temp2       ServerA
 True ServerB           100   C:\temp3       ServerA
 True ServerB           100   C:\temp5       serverA
False ServerB           22    C:\temp7
```

Comment: You narrowly beat me to this discovery - I'd never heard of join-object, but this is perfect! Thanks for the reply!